# macOS: Correct way of exposing Swift properties to Cocoa Bindings

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm working on an existing Swift/Objective-C project on the Mac and I'm creating some UI in code. I enable a button based on the selection in a NSTableView that I manage **without** using NSArrayController (for reasons).

I have a property `selectionIndexes` on `MyController`:

```
@objc var selectionIndexes : IndexSet = IndexSet()
```

I'm not sure whether the `@objc` is necessary to make it visible to the Cocoa Bindings system.

I connect the button's `enabled` binding using:

```
newButton.bind(NSBindingName.enabled, to: MyController.sharedInstance,
     withKeyPath: "selectionIndexes", 
     options: [NSBindingOption.valueTransformer : MyTransformer()])
```

This works fine, the transformer is called with the correct property and enabled is set correcty, **but changes to the selection do not trigger the binding**, so the button remains disabled.

I had to explicitly tell the system that I'm changing the value, e.g.

```
self.willChangeValue(for: \.selectionIndexes )
self.selectionIndexes = proposedSelectionIndexes
self.didChangeValue(for: \.selectionIndexes)
```

This seems pretty lame. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@objc` is necessary to expose the property to the Objective-C runtime.

To make the property key-value observing compliant you have to add the `dynamic` keyword

```
@objc dynamic var selectionIndexes = IndexSet()
```

and delete the `...ChangeValue(for` lines

Comment: Thanks. That did it.