# Cocoa Bindings on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa-bindings

I learn Cocoa Bindings on macOS https://www.raywenderlich.com/921-cocoa-bindings-on-macos#toc-anchor-009,but I use xcode13 and swift5,I do this step by step,but The first step is to bind the array controller to the table view,I find something wrong.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjW14.png),but in my project ,I cann't find this selector "SearchResultsController" like this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivx0r.png).if I ignore this problem and choose the "Array Controller" go on,Repeat the above process for Publisher TextField (Bind) by binding the value of this element to objectValue.artistName. build and run ,I will get error"Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=xxxx",I try many times just find the "Bind to"and "Model Key Path" value wrong.Can anyone tell me why? what does these two options mean?

Comment: Did you add an outlet for the array controller and what is its name?

Comment: @Willeke yes ,I did .I just find a learning video for this ,find maybe it's the NSArray Controller cann't bind to this data

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x189b09514)

Comment: I set a arraydata by myself ,then bind to ,this can work.(Because I set NSArray bind to ViewController and set the model key path is my arraydata name,this example not do this)But when I go on to change myarraydata to this examples'data(which ask for https://itunes.apple.com/search) ,I use breakpoint find this requestData is Ok.But this error will tell me"Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x189b09514)"

Comment: The tutorial is outdated. See [macOS: Correct way of exposing Swift properties to Cocoa Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964697/macos-correct-way-of-exposing-swift-properties-to-cocoa-bindings).

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem.I set the NSArray Controller bind to View Controller and model key Path = "people"(this people is a array defined by myself),when get the request Data,append it to people. So it works success!But I don't know the real reason.I doubt that NSArray Controller must bind to a exist array,because  the error with it doern't bind to .

Comment: oh ,this also a problem,this array "people" cann't be changed by "="  ,but you can removeall and append to change it .